# How to store dates when some records have month/day/year while other records have just the year?

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, database-design

I'm having difficulty deciding how to store release dates in my database of albums. Some albums have month, day, and year, but other albums have just the year. How can I store these release dates if I want to show both formats? I noticed that allmusic.com does this. My co-worker told me that he thinks they are storing the month, day, and year as separate fields in the database, but I imagine this would make it difficult to order the albums chronologically. Any recommendations on how this should be done?

I am using MySQL, but I'm asking this as a general question about relational database design.

Comment: Have you tries storing this information as a varchar field?

Comment: see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/194286/how-do-you-store-fuzzy-dates-into-a-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store the date using the DATE type and use a accuracy column.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a8f5/1)

**MySQL Schema**:

```
CREATE TABLE Album(
  Title               VARCHAR(40),
  ReleaseDate         DATE,
  ReleaseDateAccuracy ENUM('D', 'M', 'Y')
);

INSERT INTO Album
  (Title, ReleaseDate, ReleaseDateAccuracy)
VALUES
  ('Foo', '2015-01-01', 'Y'),
  ('Bar', '2015-04-01', 'M'),
  ('Baz', '2015-04-06', 'D');
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT Title,
  CASE ReleaseDateAccuracy
    WHEN 'Y' THEN DATE_FORMAT(ReleaseDate, '%Y')
    WHEN 'M' THEN DATE_FORMAT(ReleaseDate, '%Y-%m')
    WHEN 'D' THEN DATE_FORMAT(ReleaseDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
  END AS FormattedDate
  FROM Album
```

**Results**:

```
| Title | FormattedDate |
|-------|---------------|
|   Foo |          2015 |
|   Bar |       2015-04 |
|   Baz |    2015-04-06 |
```

Answer (score 1):

'2010-01-15' is a date. '2010' is not.

There are a couple of ways to deal with data like that. Using separate columns for year, month, and day is one alternative, but it has some drawbacks.

On the one hand, guaranteeing that the combined values represent a real date is complicated, especially using MySQL. MySQL doesn't enforce CHECK constraints. In your particular case--release dates of albums--you can replace a CHECK constraint with a foreign key reference to a table of valid dates.

On the other hand, the release dates of albums isn't *usually* critically important to people, so you could defend a decision to simplify your database structure and allow an occasional bad date.

Another alternative is to use `varchar(10)` to store string values like '2010' and '2010-01-15'. (Store dates like this, and they'll sort correctly without a type cast.) Complications are similar to using multiple columns (above).

For album release dates, I'd probably use varchar, and ignore the potential problem of bad data, unless there were an application-specific, compelling reason to do something more complicated.